# Find the maximum number of complex numbers α for which the matrix $αA+B$ is not invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and$ B$ be $(2017)^2 × (2017)^2$
complex matrices with $A $ being invertible. Find the
maximum number of complex numbers α for which the matrix $αA+B$ is not invertible

If  I take     $A= I_{(2017)^2 × (2017)^2}$and $B= -I_{(2017)^2 × (2017)^2}$

now  i get  $ \alpha  =   1$

Am  I correct  ???  is im on  Right track ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$\alpha A + B = A(\alpha I + A^{-1}B)=A(A^{-1}B-(-\alpha)I)$$

$\alpha A + B$ is not invertible if and only if $A^{-1}B-(-\alpha) I$ is not invertible, that is when the determinant is equal to $0$.

Think in terms of eigenvalues.

Remark:

For your attempt, you are right for your particular example of $A$ and $B$, but we have to work with general invertible $A$ and general $B$.

Comment: ah, yes, thanks for the correction.

Comment: @ Siong Thye   $A^{-1}B-(-\alpha)$  $ I$ =$A^{-1}B+\alpha I$...and the determinnant  is equal to 0 when $\alpha = -A^{-1}B$,,,,now  i can not able to proceed  further  ??? can u  more elaborate..

Comment: correction $\alpha$ is a number, it can't be equal to a matrix. think of what happens to the determinant of a matrix when the matrix is not invertible.

Comment: when eigenvalue  of  a matrix  is  0..then  matrix  will not invertible,,,but  i  can  not able to find out the value  of  $\alpha $???

Comment: The determinant of the matrix would be $0$. That is $\det(A^{-1}B- (-\alpha) I)=0$. Can you compare this to the charactheristic polynomial of $A^{-1}B$?

Comment: the characteristic polynomial   will be $A^{-1} B= \alpha I$ that is $\alpha. ({x^{(2017)^2}-1})$

Comment: The charactherisitic polynomial is $\det(A^{-1}B-\lambda I)=0$, compare it with $\det(A^{-1}B-(-\alpha)I)=0$ and you should get an relationship between $\alpha$ and $\lambda$.

Comment: ok..that  mean $\lamda = -\alpha$ that  mean $\alpha = 0$...Is  it correct now ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76484/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-henry).

Answer (score 0):

Following the same idea as @Siong we have $ \det(\alpha A+B)=\det(A)\det(\alpha I+BA^{-1})=0$ if and only if $\det(\alpha I+BA^{-1})=0$. Now by observing the degree of the polynomial $\det(x I+BA^{-1})$ we are through.